# How to get CSS to select ID of specific pattern?

Tags: css

The html page contains div ID s like q1r1, q1r2, q1r3,q2r1,q2r2,q2r3,.... How to select these ID in CSS to apply styles at once? If ID's were just q1,q2, q3.., it could be done as id^="q".

Comment: Why can't you apply a common class name to each?

Comment: `[id^="q"]` _does_ select all of those, or am I not understanding what you're wanting?

Comment: The html is auto generated through some complicated python script.

Comment: [id^="q"] will also select ids with "qrst" which are not to be selected.

Comment: You'll need to comma separate then: `[id^="q1"], [id^="q2"]`.  If all the "q#" tags have a containing element, you could use that as well: `.container [id^="q"]`.

Comment: There are tens of such ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** do `[id^q]`:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1osn7b3o/1/)

```
[id^=q] {
  // common styles
}
```

---

And if there is a certain id you would like to omit you can use `[id^=q]:not(#idname)`:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1osn7b3o/2/)

---

OR if you want to exclude ids that start with a certain pattern, combined the two like:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1osn7b3o/4/)

```
/* All ids that start with "q" but not "qr" */
[id^=q]:not([id^=qr]) { 
  // Styles here
}
```

---

BUT I would **absolutely** recommend adding a common class since that is for what they are designed. If an id can be added via python, I would think a class could be added as well.

Comment: Thanks....Almost a solution...

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

By using '^' selector the styles can be applied

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div[id^="q"] {
    background: #ffff00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="q1r1">The first div element.</div>
<div id="q1r2">The second div element.</div>
<div id="q2r2">The third div element.</div>
<p id="q2r1">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```